# Got Fabric stability alerts on the ancient app versions after the 1.3.13 Fabric update

Tags: android, google-fabric

We received a STABILITY ALERT for our Android app yesterday. Surprisingly enough, the alert was for some very old versions. Our latest app version is v24, but in the past 24 hours, Fabric reported a big spike for some early versions (<=15). Based the data collected in Mixpanel, the usage of all versions has been smooth recently. The alert looks very suspicious. I noticed there was a Fabric Android update:
https://docs.fabric.io/android/changelog.html

Is it possible that the 1.3.13 update caused a false alarm?

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. I haven't seen this issue with our apps, but if you share the package name of your app I can dig in more.

Comment: Based on what I can tell, the alert was valid but the crashes did come in from earlier versions as you mentioned. The SDK change wouldn't affect things, but perhaps a test lab that was testing older versions sent the crashes over.

Comment: Thank you Mike! The crisis seems past. The terrible started and stopped at several old versions at the exact same time.  This is really weird. We will dig into more. Again thank you for looking into it.